# Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required. Tensorflow Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have six sub-folders which are classes for my classification task. They have images extension jpg, png, jpeg which are accepted by tensorflow.

I am using the function *image_dataset_from_directory* and then I am printing the shapes of each batch just to check if they are correct.

```
for x, y in val_ds:
    print(x.shape, y.shape)
```

In this code I am getting that unknown image error.

I also used 2 scripts which I took from the similar questions which removed corrupted images.

```
from pathlib import Path
import imghdr
import shutil
destination_folder_path = '../bekar/flood_bekar'
data_dir = "./flood"
image_extensions = [".png", ".jpg", 'bmp', 'jpeg']  # add there all your images file extensions
img_type_accepted_by_tf = ["bmp", "gif", "jpeg", "png"]
for filepath in Path(data_dir).rglob("*"):
    if filepath.suffix.lower() in image_extensions:
        img_type = imghdr.what(filepath)
        destination_file_path = os.path.join(destination_folder_path, os.path.basename(filepath))
        if img_type is None:
            print(f"{filepath} is not an image")
            shutil.move(filepath, destination_file_path)
        elif img_type not in img_type_accepted_by_tf:
            print(f"{filepath} is a {img_type}, not accepted by TensorFlow")
            shutil.move(filepath, destination_file_path)
```

This removed atleast 500 images from each of the sub folders(classes)

```
import os
import cv2
import imghdr
def check_images( s_dir, ext_list):
    bad_images=[]
    bad_ext=[]
    s_list= os.listdir(s_dir)
    for klass in s_list:
        klass_path=os.path.join (s_dir, klass)
        print ('processing class directory ', klass)
        if os.path.isdir(klass_path):
            file_list = os.listdir(klass_path)
            for f in file_list:   
                f_path = os.path.join (klass_path,f)
                tip = imghdr.what(f_path)
                if ext_list.count(tip) == 0:
                  bad_images.append(f_path)
                if os.path.isfile(f_path):
                    try:
                        img = cv2.imread(f_path)
                        shape = img.shape
                    except Exception:
                        print('file ', f_path, ' is not a valid image file')
                        bad_images.append(f_path)
                else:
                    print('*** fatal error, you a sub directory ', f, ' in class directory ', klass)
        else:
            print ('*** WARNING*** you have files in ', s_dir, ' it should only contain sub directories')
    return bad_images, bad_ext
source_dir = './'
good_exts=['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp' ]
bad_file_list, bad_ext_list=check_images(source_dir, good_exts)
if len(bad_file_list) != 0:
    print('improper image files are listed below')
    for i in range (len(bad_file_list)):
        print (bad_file_list[i])
else:
    print('no improper image files were found')
```

I used the above 2 scripts to remove corrupted images but still I am getting the unknown file format error.

Comment: Not sure if you just want to get rid of *"unhappy"* images and get on with the real job, or you want to work out what's wring with the code. If the former, you can just try running `file *` to get the type of all files and search for non-images in the output.

Comment: There are only images in the folders

Comment: You can try to use [Pillow's `Image.verify` method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.verify), to find potentially more broken images. Also, you can look into [`tf.data.experimental.enable_debug_mode`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/enable_debug_mode) to make your data pipeline easier to debug.